# How to send jms message from java app to jetty webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, jms, jetty, activemq-classic

I have Jetty hightide 8.1.8.v20121106 running and have deployed a tiny webapp using jquery/javascript to listen onto a JMS topic and when a message is received it will display it on the page. I have a java app that will connect to a JMS topic and publish messages, I want those messages published by the Java app to be consumed by the webapp on Jetty.

Jetty is not connecting to tcp://localhost:61616 when the javascript webapp publishes a message or listens for a message. The logs show Jetty connecting to vm://localhost all the time. Is there any way to make Jetty use my ActiveMQ server instead of its own embedded one? Help is appreciated.

Config files below:

**jetty-plus.xml**

```
<New id="cf" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jms/connectionFactory</Arg>
    <Arg>
          <New class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                <Arg>tcp://localhost:61616</Arg>
          </New>
    </Arg>
</New>

<New id="interestingTopic"  class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jms/interestingTopic</Arg>
    <Arg>
          <New class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
                <Arg>my.test</Arg>
          </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

**web.xml** for webapp

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name>
        <param-value>tcp://localhost:61616</param-value>
        <description>The URL of the Message Broker to connect to</description>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.activemq.embeddedBroker</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        <description>Whether we should include an embedded broker or not</description>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>session</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter</filter-class>
        <!-- <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter</filter-class> -->
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>session</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
                <listener-class>org.apache.activemq.web.SessionListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/message/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <resource-env-ref>
                <resource-env-ref-name>jms/interestingTopic</resource-env-ref-name>
                <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Topic</resource-env-ref-type>
        </resource-env-ref>

    <resource-ref>
            <description>Connection Factory</description>
        <res-ref-name>jms/connectionFactory</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**My Java script code for listening on the topic**

```
window.onload = function() {
    org.activemq.Amq.init({ uri: 'amq', logging: true, timeout: 45, clientId:('geo_1') });
};

var amq = org.activemq.Amq;
var msgTopic = 'topic://my.test';
var clientId = 'geo_1';

function addTopicListener() {
    var myHandler = { 
            rcvMessage: function(message) {
                //<message type="zmg">test test</message>
                var type = message.getAttribute('type');

                switch (type) {
                    case 'zmsg':
                    {
                        var text = message.childNodes[0].data;
                        document.getElementById('zmsg_container').innerHTML += ' | '+text;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
    };

    amq.addListener('myHandler', msgTopic, myHandler.rcvMessage);
};

function delTopicListener() {
    amq.removeListener('myHandler', msgTopic);
}
```

**And lastly the code in my Java app for publishing**

```
private void init() throws NamingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
        props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"tcp://localhost:61616");
        props.setProperty("topic.test", "my.test");
        ctx = new InitialContext(props);

        System.out.println("JMS Context Initialized");
    }

    private void connect() throws NamingException, JMSException {
        connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        conn = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        myTopic = (Topic)ctx.lookup("test");
        session = conn.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        publisher = session.createPublisher(myTopic);

        System.out.println("JMS Connection started");
    }
```

Comment: Are they both actually running in the same JVM?

Comment: No they're not. I don't know where in jetty to tell it to use ActiveMQ, it keeps connecting to vm://localhost, even when i change it in the config settings above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After literally scouring the internet and going through many websites about configuring Jetty and ActiveMQ; I finally came across a website that discusses clustering jetty with activemq and having jetty use the web-console of activemq (http://java.dzone.com/articles/activemq-configuring-multiple). That website really helped.

So I was just missing an extra XML configuration section in Jetty. With the XML config I have above, I had to append the following:

```
<New id="url" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>jmx/url</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="java.lang.String">
                <Arg>service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi,service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1299/jmxrmi</Arg>
            </New>
        </Arg>
</New>
```

After that I started Jetty and ActiveMQ and sure enough jetty was connecting to ActiveMQ and not creating its own vm://localhost connection as it was doing before by default.

Thanks to those who helped, it allowed me to focus on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your java code will result in an ActiveMQ broker instance to be created in the local VM (it's a bit of a double edged sword...) :

```
props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
```

If you have another ActiveMQ broker running on **myamqhost**, then modify that line to something like this (assuming the broker is listening on port 61616):

```
props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"tcp://myamqhost:61616");
```

See [ActiveMQ JNDI Support](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html).

You might also want to look at the [ActiveMQ Ajax Client](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, now changing the provider URL on the Java code is easy. It is getting the Javascript app (on Jetty) to connect to the same ActiveMQ host as the Java app. If it's still not clear I'll let me know, I'll update my question and add jetty logs as well.